# Common Data Properties In ASP.NET MVC 2 Data Objects

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4

Okay, I've been struggling with this for a while now.

I have a standard MVC2 project and use EF4 to access data objects. Many of my data objects (and therefore database tables) have two common fields: UpdateUserAccountID and UpdateDate.

In each of my controllers, I am currently setting this fields manually within each controller on the Edit action:

```
    // POST: /Modes/Edit/2
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id, FormCollection formValues)
    {
        Mode mode = _repository.GetMode(id);

        //Set update flags
        mode.UpdateUserAccountID = _userRepository.GetUserID(User.Identity.Name);
        mode.UpdateDate = DateTime.Now;

        try
        {
             UpdateModel(mode);
             _repository.Save();
             return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = mode.ModeID });
         }
         catch
         {
             return View(mode);
         }

    }
```

Problem is, I want to update these two fields in a central place, regardless of the type of the controller. I am using Repository/IRepository pattern for my data objects. I also have set up a BaseController as I thought I could pass in my 'mode' object in the example above to a generic function in a base controller to set these two fields. But, I couldn't figure that out and the generic function has no awareness of these specific fields.

Should I be creating a base class for my repositories instead? I can't envisage how that would work within the MVC framework. In webforms, I would just have had an interface that all my models implement with the common fields but i can't seem to fit it in to an MVC approach.

Any help as to the approach to take would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This post contains a detailed solution for this scenario:
***[Entity Framework - Auditing Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808217/entity-framework-auditing-activity/3808737#3808737)***

Basically, the idea is how to update common properties like *LastModifiedBy* or *LastModifiedDate* on all entities before they saved on the data store at the EF data access layer with one common code.

You should get rid of the 2 lines of codes where you *Set update flags* and let that all happens in the *Context_SavingChanges()* like the way it has been described in the above link. Since you are in a web scenario, you have to pass *User.Identity.Name* back to your Repository.Save() method and then invoke *Repository.GetUserID()* on the *Context_SavingChanges()* as well.

This way, you don't need to update these 2 properties each and every time you insert or update an entity to the data store. It will automatically all happens in one place just before saving.