# EF Code First: Where can I find the SavingChanges Event?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

OK, this may be a newbie question, but how/where can I subscribe to the  ObjectContext.SavingChanges event as mentioned for example in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808217/entity-framework-auditing-activity/3808737#3808737).

I've only two relevant classes in my demo app: The "Country" class and a class which holds the EF Code First "definitions":

```
internal class TestDb : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Country> Countries { get; set; }       
}
```

Any hint is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be able to do this:

```
internal class TestDb : DbContext  
{  
    public void SetSavingChanges(EventHandler evt) 
    {
            var oc = this as IObjectContextAdapter;
            oc.ObjectContext.SavingChanges -= evt;
            oc.ObjectContext.SavingChanges += evt;
    }

    public DbSet<Country> Countries { get; set; }  
}
```

Comment: Don't fully understand your syntax, but the principal seems like the best way to me. The real question is if there's an even better way using EF 4.1.

Comment: @SanderRijken - What syntax don't you understand?  It's pretty straight forward.  DbContext implements the `IObjectContextAdapter` interface, that has a property called ObjectContext on it.  You cast `this` to the adapter, then use it's ObjectContext property to set the event.

Comment: `(event evt)`. I would probably expose the event as `public event EventHandler<SomeEventArgsType> SavingChanges { add { ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.SavingChanges += value; } remove { ((IObjectContextAdapater)this).ObjectContext.SavingChanges -= value; } }`

Comment: @SanderRijken - That's a possibility as well, it can be done any number of ways.  It all depends on your preference.  You really should remove and add the event in your add method, though, so the event won't get added twice.

Comment: @MystereMan is it safe to call this "SetSavingChanges" method within the constructor of TestDb?

Answer (score 2):

From what I can see on MSDN, `DbContext` wraps an instance of `ObjectContext` as a facade, not exposing this specific event.

However, `DbContext` does have a [constructor overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696505%28v=VS.103%29.aspx) that takes an `ObjectContext` - you can use this to pass in an `ObjectContext` and subscribe to the `SavingChanges` event on it.

```
using(ObjectContext context = new ObjectContext(myConnectionString))
{
  using(DbContext dbContext = new DbContext(context, true))
  {

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way may be, for example:

```
Public Class MainForm

  Private WithEvents myObjectContext As ObjectContext
  Private myDbContext As DbContext

...

  Private Sub MainForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    myDbContext = New DbContext
    myObjectContext = CType(myDbContext, IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext

...


  Private Sub ObjectContextSavingChanges(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles myObjectContext.SavingChanges

    'Your code hear

  End Sub
```