# Difference between SavingChanges event vs SaveChanges override?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I've read multiple posts about how to implement an audit log using entity framework. I currently have the audit logic embedded in the `SaveChanges` method in the `DbContext`. Please keep in mind that the code below is an EF4/5 implementation and I'm preparing to update to EF6.

```
namespace Database {
    public class AuditDetails {
        public string RemoteHost { get; set; }
        public string RevisionUser { get; set; }
        public string RevisionNotes { get; set; }
        public DateTime RevisionDateTime { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyContext : DbContext {
        // ... Unrelated overrides here ... //
        public void SaveChanges(AuditDetails auditDetails) {
            var saveCount = ProcessConcurrency();
            var items = ChangeTracker.Entries<MyEntity>().ToList();
            if (saveCount <= 0 || items == null || !items.Any() || auditDetails == null) return;
            foreach (var item in items.Select(entityEntry => entityEntry.Entity).Where(i => i != null)) {
                // ... create audit log using AuditDetails values ... //
            }
            // ... and call base.SaveChanges() ... //
        }
    }
}
```

So the questions would be:

- Is there a benefit to moving this to a `SavingChanges` event handler? Or possibly split the functionality to use both?
- Does the `AuditDetails` information preclude using `SavingChanges`?
- I do not have an override for `SaveChanges` that accepts the Boolean argument for use in transactions. How would adding that change the solution?

In Summary:

- When would you override/implement `SaveChanges` and when/why would you prefer to use a `SavingChanges` event handler?

Comment: And as an added bonus, which may be better as a new question: Would switching to an Async API change which solution to use?

Comment: Usually if you are inheriting from a class, you would override the method that gets called when the event happens, the base version of which actually calls the event. You use the event when you are handling it from a different class.

Comment: Related question with implementation of `SavingChanges` event: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808217/entity-framework-auditing-activity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it really matters in most cases. There are three situations I can think of that demand one of both options:

1. `SaveChanges` should be overridden completely, so `base.SaveChanges` should not be called: only an override can do this.
2. Another class is involved in what happens on saving changes: only the event can do that. (Or maybe I should say: an event would be the obvious pattern to choose).
3. You want to extend `SaveChanges` optionally. To my taste it's cleaner to activate the event in the constructor by some parameter than to start an override with `if (option)`, where `option` must have been stored as a member variable.

In all other cases I'd always use the override. The event requires the `ObjectContext` to be dug up first (because it's `ObjectContext.SavingChanges`). And an override is hard-wired. An event subscription can always break somehow in code maintenance.

Comment: I'm leaning toward your second item. This way I can implement auditing as a "plugin" instead of baked into the context.

Comment: Sure, that would be a valid reason. Even then, I think I would prefer to create my own event based on `DbContext`, probably carrying the context in its args object.